# The substring shouldnotexist in an operand causes std::string concatenation by + operator to return an empty string

Tags: c++, string, concatenation

Background - I was writing a benchmark to measure the cost of `stat` on a missing file and appended the string "shouldNotExist" to the end of a filepath to do so.

e.g. `/foo` should become `/fooshouldNotExist`

However, the code was just trying to stat an empty string "".

After digging a little deeper, I noticed that when concatenating two `std::string` types using the `+` operator, the result is an empty string if the result is not stored in an `std::string` immediately. For example, in the code below, I wrap it in parenthesis and convert to c_str().

I'm using `g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
int main() {
    const char *path, *x, *y;
    std::string a = "abcd";
    std::string result;

    path = (a + std::string("shouldnotexist")).c_str();
    printf("path is [%s]\n", path); // path is []

    x = std::string("shouldnotexist").c_str();
    printf("x is [%s]\n", x); // path is [shouldnotexist]

    y = (std::string("hello") + x).c_str();
    printf("y is [%s]\n", y); // path is []

    path = (a + std::string("fooo")).c_str();
    printf("path is [%s]\n", path); // path is [abcdfoo]

    path = (a + std::string("foooshouldnotexist")).c_str();
    printf("path is [%s]\n", path); //path is []

    path = (std::string("fooshouldnotexist") + a).c_str();
    printf("path is [%s]\n", path); // path is []

    result = std::string("fooshouldnotexist") + a;
    // Storing in an intermediate std::string appears to work
    // path is [fooshouldnotexistabcd], length is 21
    printf("path is [%s], length is %lu\n", result.c_str(), result.length());

    return 0;
}
```

Are you observing a similar result? If so, why does this happen and is it documented anywhere?

Comment: Why not just use std::string path, x, y instead? IIRC, there were some problems operating with const char pointer and std::string.

Comment: My best guess is that (a + b).c_str() is leaving C pointing at invalid memory, as + creates a temporary string that will go out of scope and be destructed when the statement is finished. The above is fine when passing (a + b).c_str() to a function parameter, but not when assigning it to a variable. Although, I'm not quite sure why it sometimes does work. -- Another wild guess is that there is a limit of binary size that is defaulted in the memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c_str` gives you a pointer to the contents of a string instance to use in plain-C functions (like printf). However, when you apply it on a *temporary* string instance created by e.g. concatenation, it is invalidated immediately afterwards, as the temporary object goes out of scope:

1. A temporary string instance for the concatenated string is created: `std::string _temporary = a + std::string("shouldnotexist");`
2. The `c_str` method is called on it, storing the result: `path = _temporary.c_str()`
3. The temporary instance goes out of scope, deleting the string, invalidating the pointer stored in `path`.
4. You use the now-invalid stored pointer for `printf`.

As you write, by storing the temporary instance in a variable, the problem goes away, because now the instance does not go out of scope prior to the printf, keeping the pointer valid.

Comment: But why does it work on `path = (a + std::string("fooo")).c_str();` and not on `path = (a + std::string("foooshouldnotexist")).c_str();` ?

Comment: @algrebe because undefined behaviour is not required to be consistent.